# Chrome jumps whenever I use click on a textbox editable by TinyMce

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce, css-position

I'm using TinyMCE with a "position:fixed" external toolbar.

The problem is whenever I click on a div which, on a click, becomes editable by tinyMCE, the whole Chrome page  jumps so that the toolbar is always at a certain location on the page after that click.

How can I prevent the jump?

When a person clicks on a div, (whose ID is `ta_id`), this is the part of the code (of the plugin that's attached to that div:

```
            tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, ta_id);
            $('#'+ta_id+'_tbl').css("width",'100%');
            divheight = $this.css('height');
            $('#'+ta_id+'_tbl').css("height",divheight);
            $('#'+ta_id+'_ifr').attr('scrolling','no');
            $('#'+ta_id+'_ifr').css('overflow-y','hidden');
            $('#'+ta_id+'_ifr').css("height",divheight);
            $this.resizable("option","disabled",true);
            $this.draggable("option","disabled",true);
```

If I click on the div in FF or IE, it's gets editable by TinyMCE without any annoying jumps.